# Correct syntax to call a mailer with interpolation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a method to dynamically call a mailer that look like this :

```
def mail
  application = mail[:application].capitalize
  class_template = mail[:template].split('/').[0]+ 'Mailer'
  template = mail[:template].split('/').second
  email_params = mail[:params].values.map(&:inspect).join(', ')

  "#{application}::#{class_template}.#{template}(#{email_params}).deliver_now"
   # Here I have something like : "Application::TemplatetMailer.test_name(\"John\", \"Doe\").deliver_now"
end
```

How can I have something like :

```
Application::TemplatetMailer.test(\"John\", \"Doe\").deliver_now
```

instead of

```
"Application::TemplatetMailer.test(\"John\", \"Doe\").deliver_now"
```

Comment: You could do that using `eval`, but you should probably think about another approach.

Comment: All of this can be done with `constantize` (Rails) and `send` (Ruby). **DO NOT USE `eval`**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look up arbitrary constants with [`constantize`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-constantize):

```rb
mailer = [ application, class_template ].join('::').constantize

mailer.send(template, *email_params).deliver_now
```

> Be **extremely** careful with what access you allow to end users. Do not expose this in a way that allows them to make arbitrary method calls on arbitrary classes. Having an allow-list of classes and methods is *way* safer.

Comment: constantize does not seems to work on array, do you have any ideas on how to do it on those strings ?

Comment: Sorry, got distracted before I could close that out. Edited.

Comment: Thx for your help, now I have the error `uninitialized constant Application::TemplatetMailer (NameError)` do you know where it comes from ?

Comment: Maybe spelling it as "Templatet" instead of presumably "Template"? This code will only work of the classes are defined as specified.